# String splitting methods in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

Output of a single string is

> iPad Stylus & Ballpoint Pen
>  Usually ships in 24 hrs
>   $9.99

I want save each line of above string into separate strings  like:

```
String one = "iPad Stylus & Ballpoint Pen";  
String two = "Usually ships in 24 hrs";  
String three = "$9.99";
```

What method should use for it?

Comment: so you want to split every line?

Comment: i wanna to save every line in separate veriables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String inputString = " iPad Stylus & Ballpoint Pen    
     Usually ships in 24 hrs    
    $9.99";



String lines[] = inputString.split("\\r?\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Splitter splitter = Splitter.on('\n').trimResults().omitEmptyStrings();
Iterable<String> items = splitter.split(text);
```

> See **[Guava Explained > Strings > Splitter](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter)**